# The function is returning undefined although the inner console log is showing the value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome extension and the function for the active tab URL is returning an undefined value, although the inner console log is showing the URL

PS: I am a noob in terms of Javascript

```
function tabURL()
{
  var tabUrl;
  chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true,active: true}, function(tabs) {
    tabUrl = tabs[0].url;
    console.log(tabUrl); //Showing the right URL
  });

  console.log(tabUrl); //Showing undefined
   return tabUrl;
}
```

I expect the activeTab URL but the actual output is undefined

Comment: Chrome API is asynchronous so you'll have to rework your code to use callbacks or Promises with async/await (you can simply load Mozilla's WebExtensions polyfill). BTW not related to the issue but you have a typo in the variable name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks, I think I have to learn about promises and also I have rectified the typo, it was just in the question. Also, can you suggest any youtube video or an article which covers all these topics

Comment: I don't know which tutorials are good, but AFAIK the easiest approach is to start with async/await syntax, make it work to grasp the concept, then optionally study the underlying mechanism of Promises.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried all the approaches using Async and await but wasn't able to get the output. So could you please post an answer to this question to make a function that returns the URL whenever called. Thanks

Comment: I think this is something basic (provided you're using the polyfill I mentioned) that one must tackle oneself so maybe others will post an answer.